# What will happen if https traffic goes through the WAF?

Tags: tls, http, waf

A web application firewall (WAF) is an application firewall for HTTP applications. It applies a set of rules to an HTTP conversation. Generally, these rules cover common attacks such as Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) and SQL Injection.

So from what I understand, this will handle only HTTP. What will happen if HTTPS traffic goes through the WAF?

Does it reduce the request time? or are there any performance issues?

Comment: Is your question about performance or security?

Comment: I want to know, is it reduce the performance?

Comment: That's not a security question, then.

Comment: I can see that the statement ```...is an application firewall for HTTP applications``` can be confusing. In my opinion it would have been better to use the term web applications and leave the protocol out of it.

Comment: Adding any security filtering will negatively impact performance. Especially at the application layer.

Comment: @user2320464 ,but waf only work with http, so what will happen for the https request?

Comment: Have a look at [this short read](https://www.loadbalancer.org/blog/secure-connections-encrypt-traffic-when-using-a-waf/).